# Using stable_sort() to sort doubles as ints

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a huge array of ints that I need to sort. The catch here is that each entry in the list has a number of other associated elements in it that need to follow that int around as it gets sorted. I've kind of solved this problem by changing the sorting to sort doubles instead of ints. I've tagged each number before it was sorted with a fractional part denoting that value's original location before the sort, thus allowing me to reference it's associated data and allowing me to efficiently rebuild the sorted list with all the associated elements.

My problem is that I want to sort the double values by ints using the function stable_sort().

I'm referring to this web page: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/stable_sort/

However, since I'm a new programmer, i don't quite understand how they managed to get the sort by ints to work. What exactly am i supposed to put into that third argument to make the function work? (i know i can just copy and paste it and make it work, but i want to learn and understand this too).

Thanks,

-Faken

Edit: Please note that I'm a new programmer who has had no formal programming training. I'm learning as i go so please keep your explanations as simple and as rudimentary as possible.

In short, please treat me as if i have never seen c++ code before.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to add an extra integer field denoting the original position and dela with it in a comparison function?

Comment: What exactly is this stuff about associated data? It can almost certainly be done better. Tell us what you're actually doing.

Comment: @sharptooth: i don't quite understand what your trying to say. Earlier i had been trying to write my own merge sort algorithm which sorts a list with an attached second list to keep track of the origonal position. Then i found out about the function stable_sort()... If there is another standard function that can do this already, please let me know.

Comment: @GMan: well...the function is actually sorting a 2D array in the form of a 1D list. There are also a number of other values (on separate arrays) that are associated with that particular grid location (although they are not to be sorted). I need to preserve the xy location as well as the other variables attributed to that location. Basically, i just need to store the xy data and then everything else can be reconstructed from there.

Comment: If you learned data structures in C++, you would know you could use something like a `map` to associate coordinates with data.

Comment: @Faken: What exactly is in the array? You say that there're "associated properties". How are they associated? If they are in the same struct you could possibly add a field into that struct denoting original position instead of changing int to double.

Comment: @sharptooth: Well, this has a lot to do with my thesis (in mechanical engineering). My thesis is on automated part fixturing given g-code and a CAD file, and my own designed "universal fixture". So far, I've been writing code to extract things such as gradient data, topographical data (and a few other things) based off projections. This data depends on xy data. This data is then fed through a scoring scheme and the score for each point on the grid is then ranked. All other data must go along with that rank (which other data is stored and outputted in different txt files).

Comment: continued...This is what those other associated properties are. I need to hang onto their position information for pruning. Since I have limited programming experience, my methods may end up seeming odd to those with more experience. I may not know much about programming so im forced to make due by using "out of the box" ideas...many of which may not be the most efficient method, but it still works. The goal of my thesis is to make it work, if they wish to pursue the project further, ill leave it up to a real comp sci student! I'm just a poor mechanical engineering student!

Comment: No problem. Why not introduce a struct and store the integer in question, all properties corresponding to that integer and the initial integer position in that structure?

Comment: @sharptooth: I'll look into structs, I've never had to use them before. Any suggestions on a good place to start?

Comment: Will this help http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/structures.html ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you say you're not familiar with vectors (you really should learn STL containers ASAP, though), I assume you're playing with arrays. Something along these lines:

```
int a[] = { 3, 1, 2 };
std::stable_sort(&a[0], &a[3]);
```

The third optional argument `f` of `stable_sort` is a *function object* - that is, anything which can be called like a function by following it with parentheses - `f(a, b)`. A function (or rather a pointer to one) is a function object; other kinds include classes with overloaded `operator()`, but for your purposes a plain function would probably do.

Now you have your data type with `int` field on which you want to sort, and some additional data:

```
struct foo {
  int n;
  // data
  ...
};

foo a[] = { ... };
```

To sort this (or anything, really), `stable_sort` needs to have some way of comparing any two elements to see which one is greater. By default it simply uses operator `<` to compare; if the element type supports it directly, that is. Obviously, `int` does; it is also possible to overload `operator<` for your struct, and it will be picked up as well, but you asked about a different approach.

This is what the third argument is for - when it is provided, `stable_sort` calls it every time it needs to make a comparison, passing two elements as the arguments to the call. The called function (or function object, in general) must return `true` if first argument is less than second for the purpose of sorting, or `false` if it is greater or equal - in other words, it must work like operator `<` itself does (except that you define the way you want things to be compared). For `foo`, you just want to compare `n`, and leave the rest alone. So:

```
bool compare_foo_n(const foo& l, const foo& r) {
  return l.n < r.n;
}
```

And now you use it by passing the pointer to this function (represented simply by its name) to `stable_sort`:

```
std::stable_sort(&a[0], &a[3], compare_foo_n);
```

Comment: Ahh thank you, I think i understand now. So this means I can also control how the function sorts the list. This means if i use < as the comparator, i get a lowest to highest, and if i use the > ill get a highest to lowest.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the comparison function. Something like this:

```
bool intCompare(double first, double second)
{
    return static_cast<int>(first) < static_cast<int>(second);
}

int  main()
{

    std::vector<double> v;
    v.push_back(1.4);
    v.push_back(1.3);   
    v.push_back(2.1);
    v.push_back(1.5);

    std::stable_sort(v.begin(), v.end(), intCompare);



    return 0;
}
```

Inside the sort algorithm, to compare the values the comparison function passed by you is used. If you have a more complex data structure and want to sort on a particular attribute of the data structure then you can use this user-defined function to compare the values.

Comment: Umm...whats a vector? push_back? Sorry, this explanation is too advanced for me.

Comment: If you don't know what `vectors` are, you probably aren't ready to be trying what you're doing. Get a good book and make sure you learn the language well!

Comment: @GMan: Well, I'm learning as i go. To be honest, i got thrown off the deep end with this to start off with anyways. Playing around with the code, i found that i don't need vectors to actually make the function work, just simple heap arrays work just fine as well.

Comment: The problem is your assumption of "just as fine". As a beginner, you should be careful making these assumptions, since you don't know enough to know if that's true.

Comment: @GMan: If that is the case and in this case, it won't work, please enlighten me.

Comment: Use `vectors`. :P I'm sure you could make it work, but using a vector takes away the need to worry about the array part and focus on the algorithm part.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are talking about this function:

```
bool compare_as_ints (double i,double j)
{
  return (int(i)<int(j));
}
```

And the function call:

```
stable_sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), compare_as_ints);
```

The function `compare_as_ints` is a normal function but this is being passed to the `stable_sort` as a function pointer. i.e., the address of the function is being passed which would be used by `stable_sort` internally to compare the values.

Look at this [function pointer tutorial](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html) if you are unclear about this.